# Why is this a bad PNG for 9-Patching?

Tags: android, nine-patch

It seems every attempt I've made at creating a 9-Patch file has created a situation where the 'Content' in the Draw 9-Patch is always 'Bad'. Here is my latest (and very simple) PNG that is shown as all bad pixels:

[image: Bad PNG Content]

Could I please be enlightened as to why this is 'bad'? And how am I suppose to know what is good or bad if Android does not explicitly state any criteria in the SDK docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This PNG is fine. What you're supposed to do with the [draw 9-patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) is to select the areas which are stretchable. Don't select the two pixel area where your two colors meet. Here's the 9-patch I created from your PNG:

[image: 9-patch]

Comment: Thank you. The 'Bad Patches' being apparent immediately is a tad misleading. I appreciate the help!

Comment: But if the colormap is 1-bit, as in the original image, you cannot set some pixels as transparent, that's why my answer directed the OP to fix that first.

Comment: Also, setting the content area as two separate pixels in the different colored areas is not correct. It does need to span over where the two colors meet in order for the text to be printed slightly off center (1 pixel below) of the border where the two colors meet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your image does not have a 1-pixel border all around defining the stretchable area and (optionally) the content area. This border is a requirement. The criteria for 9-patches is discussed in the document [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). There's also the [Draw 9-patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) to help you draw 9-patches.

Comment: According to the documentation the pixel border is added using the 'Draw 9-Patch' utility, however when I load the image it simply indicates that the entire image is bad content. Does it ALWAYS say that to begin with?

Comment: @NickBetcher - It's been a while since I used the tool. As I recall, the image already has to have the border area. The tool is used to add the lines in the border and preview the effects of having the lines in different places.

Comment: Not sure if it used to be this way, but you don't have to manually create the border area in the latest few releases of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The colormap of you bitmap is wrong:

```
correct.9.png: PNG image data, w x h, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
buttonbg.9.png: PNG image data, 6 x 21, 1-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Comment: I've since fixed that. It doesn't have a problem to begin with though per the 'Accepted' answer.